# css menu: ie7&8 problem, css not used?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Please have a look at the menu at my site: http://server.patrikelfstrom.se/johan/fysiosteo/

In FF & chrome, it works as it should. But the css doesnt seem to get used in IE and i cant figure out why. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: refreshing the page caused it to work for me O_o ... weird

Comment: Nvm, the problem was that i was using a <nav> element, which IE couldnt handle.

Comment: You should put it down as an answer so that you can accept it. People might even upvote you as well.

Comment: Consider using a [shiv](http://www.google.ca/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=html5shiv) to let IE handle html5 elements rather than coding to the lowest denominator.

Answer (score 0):

Just i see your code in firebug. You used -moz-linear-gradient and box-shadow properties. I think this is not support lower version ie.

Comment: @Johan - your fallback just sets a plain background, which is fine... but you may want to look up http://css3pie.com/ to get IE6/7/8 to support CSS3 gradients and other features.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this: 
`<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->`
 into your code to allow the `nav` element to work in lower versions of IE.